# Searching channel entries using playa field

Tags: channel-entries, playa, search, url-title, entryid

Im trying to send off the following channel entries request.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" search:crops="{segment_3}"} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The crops field is a Playa field. If i use `{crops}` tag in my template, i get entry_id(s), rather than the `url_title` or `title`.

Shouldn't `search:crops` try to match both `entry_id` and `url_title`?

If not, is there a way of getting `{entry_id}` from `{url_title}` if I know it is equal to `{segment_3}`, so that i call:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" search:crops="{segment_3_entry_id}"} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is there anything else I should be doing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What happens if you use `{crops}{title}{/crops}` since Playa is always used with a tag pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't test it but I assume if you use url_title="{segment_3}" it would be the same as entry_id and search this specific entry+

otherwise you are searching all entry's in your channel

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html

Comment: thanks, switched to dynamic="no" and now works like a charm!